# JavaFx jar application. FXML not found?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I have created a new JavaFX 2.0 applicarion using eclipse. My file structure is this

```
src
    application
        Main.java
        HomeController.java
        ...other .java files
    fxml
        homeview.fxml
        ...other fxml files
lib
     ...jar library files
```

Now if i export my program as a jar file i got an error saying /fxml/homeview.fxml not found?

To load the fxml file i am using

```
getClass.getResource("/fxml/homeview.fxml");
```

This works fine when i run the program under eclipse.

Comment: Maybe remove the leading `/`?

Comment: How are you trying to load the `fxml` ?

Comment: How are you creating the jar? Have you checked that the .fxml file is really inside the jar? What kind of directory structure do you have in the jar?